# JQuery not finding nth-child

Tags: jquery

I'm modifying this [great post](http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2012/May/9/using-jquery-sum-values-table-column) to sum the values of each column in a table. The reason I'm using it is because the table can be unlimited rows and columns.

In this mod, I need to get the values of a text input instead of the cell text. I've change the 2nd line of the sumOfColumns() function to include a find `find("input:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")` to get all the table row's inputs instead of the `children("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")`. However it is not finding them. I though find() gets all children regardless of depth?

```
function sumOfColumns(table, columnIndex) {
    var tot = 0;
    table.find("tr").find("input:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")
    .each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);
        if (!$this.hasClass("sum")) {
            tot += parseInt($this.value());
        }
    });
    return tot;
}

function do_sums() {
$("tr.sum").each(function(i, tr) {
    $tr = $(tr);
    //console.log($tr);
    $tr.children().each(function(i, td) {
        $td = $(td);
        //console.log($td);
        var table = $td.parent().parent().parent();
        if ($td.hasClass("sum")) {
            $td.html(sumOfColumns(table, i+1));
        }
    })
});
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>balance</th>
        <td><input type="text" onchange="do_sums();"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>gains</th>
        <td><input type="text" onchange="do_sums();"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>loses</th>
        <td>-<input type="text" onchange="do_sums();"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="sum">
        <th>Total</th>

        <td class="sum">#</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the value of each input per column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're looking for an `input` which is the nth child, but the `input` isn't the nth child of it's parent (the td).

What you really want to find is an `input` that's inside a `td` that's the nth child.

`find("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ") input")`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that, rookie mistake. Thanks!